# How can I make moderate-vigorous physical exercise a habit?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding

Moderate-vigorous physical exercise is a form of physical activity that requires moderate to high levels of effort and increases your heart rate and breathing rate. Some examples of moderate-vigorous physical exercise:

- [Brisk walking: Walking at a pace of 3-4 miles per hour.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887.)
- [Biking: Biking at a speed of 10-12 miles per hour.](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/obesity-prevention-source/moderate-and-vigorous-physical-activity/.)
- [Swimming: Swimming laps or doing water aerobics.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887.)
- [Mowing the lawn: Mowing the lawn with a power mower.](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/obesity-prevention-source/moderate-and-vigorous-physical-activity/.)
- [Dancing: Aerobic dancing or Zumba.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887.)
- [Strength training: Strength training for all major muscle groups at least two times a week.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887.)

[It is recommended that healthy adults get at least 150 minutes of moderate aerobic activity or 75 minutes of vigorous aerobic activity per week. Additionally, strength training should be done for all major muscle groups at least two times a week. However, it is important to consult with a healthcare professional before starting any new exercise routine.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887.) How can I make it a habit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just gonna answer this in relation to walking/biking, as this is what I'm most experienced at: Over the last 2 years, I went from struggling to walk 15minutes a day to getting over 20k steps nearly every day.

What helped me in the beginning, was tracking my daily steps. You can get fitness trackers very cheap or use your smartphone. I set small goals in the beginning, my first goal was 3000 steps daily. If I didn't have those steps at a certain time, I forced myself to go outside. Over time, I slowly increased that goal. When I increased that goal, often I needed to do like > 1 hour walks in the evening, and often wasn't very motivated to do them. What helped me to do them anyway, was restricting podcast usage or longer phone talks to be done while outside. My desire to listen to these podcasts or talk to a friend, gave me the drive to go outside.

Whenever I had to got somewhere, I asked myself: Can I somehow get there by foot/bike? Bus/Train in addition to walking?
At first it will sometimes sound insane: Instead of a 10minute car ride i'm gonna walk for an hour?
But I wanted to invest the time in my health anyway, so using that time was worth it.

Over time, your perception of distances and where you can get without a car changes a lot. Going by foot or bike becomes a real option in your mind, and really becomes a habit.

I sold my car eventually, and I now walk 45mins to and from work everyday, and get around everywhere using my own legs. It's a daily habit and my first option when figuring out, how i can get to places: can i get there by foot or bike? Even if I use bus/train, that also involves more walking than getting around by car. I know that not everyone has the infrastructure to support this, but not all car rides are necessary :)

So in summary. Every habit needs to start with some goal setting and figuring out what works for you. You also need a plan, on how to do these habits even if you don't feel like doing them.
Just start doing it, and keep doing it - if you do it often enough it will become a habit :)